# transforming log text to regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Error when trying to convert following string in to regex expression format using following expression.

```
^([[^]]+]) ([[^]]+]) (-|[a-z,A-Z,\s,\W]*)
```

> 2017-06-12 02:59:06.875 o.b.c.d.j.k.authoreduser [INFO] user =
>   qa-excel, principal = qa-excel@hr.local attempting to user =
>   ambari-server-dev-excel for operation = getInfo from host=
>   /00.000.00.00

Comment: Error when reading your post, cannot answer inexistant question.

Comment: More seriously, your first two character classes seem off. If you're trying to match anything but `]`, `[^]]` should work. If the first `[` should be understood as a literal character, it should be escaped. `\[[^]]+]` will represent a non-empty sequence of non-`]`characters enclosed in `[...]`

Comment: Also `\W` contains `\s`, `,` have no special meaning inside character classes and `-` can be represented inside a character class by being placed last, first, or being escaped. I guess what you were looking for was `^(\[[^]]+]) (\[[^]]+]) ([-a-zA-Z\W]*)`. Note that this is still quite far from matching your log format.

Comment: What exactly is each part of the regex suppose to match?

Comment: i dont have much idea about regex but the the regex pattern should match to string         2017-06-12 02:59:06.875 o.b.c.d.j.k.authoreduser [INFO] user = qa-excel, principal = qa-excel@hr.local attempting to user = ambari-server-dev-excel for operation = getInfo from host= /00.000.00.00

Comment: Do you want just to validate the string or to extract some data?

Comment: dmitry i just need to validate the string

Comment: What exactly is the criteria?

Comment: This question was posted yesterday, but was deleted after my comment. Please do not delete your questions. Just provide details so that someone could answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to find all messages similar to the one in the example.
The following regex validates that there is date/time field, user id, type in square brackets, and the rest of the line anything:

```
^[\d -]+ [\d\:\.]+ [^\[]*\[[^\]]+\].*$
```